# How does one prevent Facebook from automatically combining uploaded photos in the timeline?

Tags: facebook

If I use the secret email address to upload photos to my Facebook timeline, the photos will automatically be shown in one single post if I upload them within a certain timespan (after a day or so, Facebook will create a new post. Apparently the engine assumes that images uploaded one after the other somehow belong together).

**Is there a way to always make Facebook use one post per image**, even if the images are part of one album, no matter how short the timespan between each upload?

(I know I can use different albums, but I don't know how to do that using the email function. And sorry if I didn't get the terminology right - I'm a Facebook newbie AND German)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the photos are part of the same album, I do not see the need to clutter friend feeds with multiple posts. Facebook clumps events, they have even started clumping interests (friends talking about Harry Potter) to clear up the streams. So I do not think separate posts for the same event (i.e. adding photos to the same album) is possible.

Using the personalized email address all photos will be sent to the Mobile Uploads album. You then need to access the non-mobile site from a browser and make your changes to the appropriate album. So edit the mobile uploads album and move the photos to the appropriate album. The events (posts) will then re-adjust themselves to the new events such as

> phwd added 3 new photos to the album Pancakes
>
> phwd added 2 new photos to the album Running

instead of

> phwd added 5 new photos to the album Mobile Uploads

Comment: Thanks, but there is a reason for the need to publish uploads as multiple posts (which I should have mentioned, I guess). This is for a political cartoonist's fan page, and he usually publishes one and sometimes two cartoons a day on his php website, and at the same time sends it to FB. Interestingly, more people look into it if they come as single posts (as they do when posted on different days), and there are more comments. AND it looks nicer. Well, the obvious solution is not to send emails but to use the API.

Comment: Yeah... you did not say it was a fan page. The solution is indeed to use the API or an app readily available for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the picture you want to separate from the other(s) and change the time by setting an earlier date to it.

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

Share the pictures first on your timeline and then move them to the album. Click the picture for fullscreens view, settings, move to another album.
A bit extra work, but no lumping anymore :)